# querying documents directory objects ios

Tags: ios, uitableview, if-statement, nsdocumentdirectory

I have images in uitableview, they each have a string for they're path in documents directory.
Now my trouble is if somebody adds the same image they will have the same path.
I was thinking of making an if-statement that will run on all of my fetchedResultsController objects or better yet my entire documents directory and append a number or something to the pathString.
lets say user adds title.jpg to doc directory, then he adds the same image then I want a check to see if it already exists, if it already exists in doc directory then append title(1).jpg so it can save properly and so on.

any efficient way of doing that ?

Comment: not need to check imaagename in docement directory but set imagename like random number or current datatime

Comment: great idea going by date. I was thinkin bout somesort of hash number but that works too!. thx a bunch kind sir!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the OS you're targeting you can set the image name using `NSUUID`. If you're targeting < iOS 6 you'll have to use `CFUUIDRef`. This will always ensure you have a unique filename for an image.

Comment: thx a bunch. this is how I used it :                                NSUUID * uniqueImageID = [NSUUID UUID];
NSString* imageName = [uniqueImageID UUIDString];
works great!